# Extract data from client database

Tags: python, mysql

I have to send multiple data through Python from a DB allocated in the client to the Main DB in the server, what's the best solution to this? I currently have my web server up and functioning, I can fill my DB locally, but I don't really know how to do it remotely, I'm using Python in my hardware.

Here is what I have so far in the client:

```
import mysql.connector
cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='user', password='pass', host='url?', database='db') #im able to enter with this
cursor = cnx.cursor()
query = ("INSERT INTO IGNORE table " "(id,date,son) " "VALUES( (%s,%s,%s)")
for row in data: #ive already extracted data from the other DB
cursor.execute(query, (row[0],row[1],row[2]))
```

which yeilds an error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IGNORE table(id,date,son) VALUES (number, '2017-11-09 14:33:15', 18.987)' at line 1

Comment: does `http://MyIP/index.html` work?  if not, that's your issue or you might need `/index.html` instead of `index.html` but I don't know if that is an issue

Comment: Well if you're really trying to send info, you're going to need a POST, not a GET. So that's a good place to start.

Comment: i can connect through html to my server, since i get a response, i found my problem now its that i cant connect to the SQL DB remotely, i can connect on the VM but if i try from outside using:
mysql -h MYIP -u user -ppassword

i get no response at all, it freezes, i already allowed tcp port forwarding and GRANT privileges on DB, any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the issue with the MySQL port in the following way: I opened the port internally from my VM instead of from my Virtual Network (I'm using the Google Cloud Platform).

Answer (score 2):

One possibility - Make sure your mysqld service is binding to your external ip address (set in your mysql config file on the server).  By default I believe it binds to 127.0.0.1 or localhost.  If it is binding to localhost, your db will never respond to external requests.